# Single .gitignore for parent folder with multiple unity projects

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I have the following `.gitignore` for my unity project parent folder which has multiple unity game folders inside. I have tried using `git rm --cached` as well but it seems like it is not stopping the tracking of library folder. The folder structure is as follows, where Car Racing, Hat trick etc, are all independent unity game folders.
[image]

```
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# Visual Studio 2015 cache directory
/.vs/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

# Data generated by Visage tracking
*EMOTION*.txt
/*/*-*-*-*-*-*-*.txt
```

Comment: shouldn't a `*/` at the beginning solve it? like `*/[Ll]ibrary/` and so on?

Comment: I tried it, didn't work.

Comment: If you already committed it once before than files stay tracked even if they are added to gitignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure those "independent unity game folders" don't have their own .git subfolder: that would make them nested Git repo within your main parent repo, and your main `.gitignore` file would be ignored in those sub-repo.

You can also make sure a file is still *not* ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- a/path/to/file
```

That being said, `git rm --cached` alone is not enough.

As the [OP vipin8169](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629932/vipin8169) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725680/single-gitignore-for-parent-folder-with-multiple-unity-projects/48727773?noredirect=1#comment84456811_48727773) (and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839198/6309)), this is better:

```
 git ls-files --ignored --exclude-standard -z | \
    xargs -0 git rm --cached
 git commit -am "Remove ignored files
```

Comment: No, there is only one gitignore file

Comment: @vipin8169 OK, so what is the issue? What file is not ignored that should be ignored?

Comment: All the lib folders

Comment: @vipin8169 Can you give an example of a full path which should be ignored? What rule in your .gitignore should have ignored that file?

Comment: These files were checked by someone else, and he checked in all the library folders and everything which should have been a part of gitignore. I updated the gitignore to the one i mentioned in question above and also did `git rm -r --cached`, but still they are getting tracked by git

Comment: For example `\Pedastals\Library\*` should have been ignored which is not the case

Comment: I am using the same gitignore in an another project with similar structure, and it is working fine there. I wonder what is happening in this case, I have tried doing whatever I can with no luck

Comment: Can you try, for testing, to modify your .gitignore with library/ and Library/ instead of the current [Ll]ibrary/?

Comment: `git rm -r --cahed` didn't work, but `git ls-files --ignored --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached` worked. seems like it is fixed by using this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839198/1629932

Comment: @vipin8169 Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.